# UIWebView displaying white screen for locally loaded images

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiwebview

I am writing my first iOS app (only for iPad) using `Swift` in which,app will load html based on resources present on the app and the values user has selected.I am using the following function to load data on `UIWebView`. All the resources are present in the project.

```
        let url =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(updatedResource, withExtension: "html")
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        htmlWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
```

`url` is the name of the resource that needs to be loaded.

`print("This is the request \(htmlWebView.request)")` is giving me value as

```
This is the request Optional(<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fc180589a00> { URL: file:///Users/ios/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CB5ACC92-856E-4CBE-B4D4-03B0C1774765/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C588D7E2-15F0-406A-8B09-227E2284459E/DemoHTML5.app/file3.html })
```

Previously, I had deployed the app on iPad Mini simulator, however it shows whitescreen when deployed on iPad 2/iPad Air simulator

**P.S :**  I am using XCode 6.1 and running the app on iOS 8.1 ( OS 10.11 upgrade is in progress ) . All the resources are present in the app

Comment: White screen remains forever or for sort time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine for me.  My guess is you have a problem with your storyboard on the iPad.  Here's a sample project that demonstrates the solution:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xekspq2otqoq3l/SimpleWebViewLoader.zip?dl=0

The code in it is quite simple:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "html")
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj) 
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I included the zip so you could run it and see if it works differently for you.  Note I am using Xcode 7.3.  It's generally recommended that you see up to date on Xcode releases.